# Knowing the rates of gain and loss, estimate the average amount.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, estimation

This question was presented to me as such:

> Say that people grow 100 hairs a day and lose 100 hairs a day and hairs have a lifespan of 100 days. Estimate how much hair an average person would have.

I thought to answer this I would assume there were no hairs to start, so each day 100 more hairs show up until the first 100 hairs' lifespans end, at which point there would be equilibrium, so the estimate would be around 100 * 100 = 10,000 hairs. I feel as though this answer is incomplete or that I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

(Forgive me if I put an improper tag)

Comment: If you grow 100 hairs a day and lose 100 hairs a day, there is no net change to the amount of hairs on your head.

Comment: You might be interested in Little's Law.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law

Comment: Ah, thank you @awkward; exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am confused why the lifespan matters when you are loosing hairs at the same rate? I am confused because if you start with no hair, you loose the hair you grow before it even dies keeping it at no hair.